# VBA 1004 error : Application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I am a novice at Excel VBA and am running into an error 1004 while compiling a portion of the code:

```
Cells(i, j).Formula = _"=vlookup(Cells(i,1).Value,SKULifeCycle_Table_Temp!R1C1:R5000C500,match(Cells(1,j).Value,'SKULifeCycle_Table_Temp'!R1C1:R1C500,0),0)"
```

`i` and `j` have been defined previously as integers and are part of a for loop. Could anyone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 4):

A few things wrong there:

First, you're using the literal text "Cells(i, 1).Value" and "Cells(1, j).Value" in the formula string. You would need to concatenate the values into the string like this:

```
Cells(i, j).FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(" & Cells(i,1).Value & ",SKULifeCycle_Table_Temp!R1C1:R5000C500,match(" & Cells(1,j).Value & ",'SKULifeCycle_Table_Temp'!R1C1:R1C500,0),0)"
```

Second, you used the `.Formula` property but passed R1C1 style references, so you should use the `.FormulaR1C1` property (as I did above).

Third, if the values in the cells that you are using for the lookup values are text, you need to enclose them in quotes:

```
    Cells(i, j).FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(""" & Cells(i,1).Value & """,SKULifeCycle_Table_Temp!R1C1:R5000C500,match(""" & Cells(1,j).Value & """,'SKULifeCycle_Table_Temp'!R1C1:R1C500,0),0)"
```

or use the addresses (in R1C1 format) instead:

```
Cells(i, j).FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC1,SKULifeCycle_Table_Temp!R1C1:R5000C500,match(R1C,'SKULifeCycle_Table_Temp'!R1C1:R1C500,0),0)"
```

Answer (score 1):

One issue that is clear (maybe the cause of the whole error), is that variables are being used *within* a string. So, what does that mean? I'll simplify using the code below as a template:

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim i as Integer
    Dim j as Integer

    i = 2
    j = 3

    Cells(i, j).Value = "The row number is i and the column number is j"
End Sub
```

In the `Cells` line, it correctly refers to cell `C2`, which is the second row and third column. But what value is inserted into the cell? It's literally `"The row number is i and the column number is j"` using the letters, and not their corresponding numbers. Similarly, in your case, the formula will read: `VLOOKUP(CELLS(i,1)...` using the letter i, which is incorrect.

Additionally, a cell's formula doesn't use the `CELLS` syntax. You instead need to build a string using the variables. It would look a lot like:

```
"=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(i, 1).Address & "SKULifeCycle_Table_Temp!R1C1:R5000C500, Match(" & Cells(i, 1)Address ... "
```

Try to build out your formula string and refer back to this post with any specific questions.